# problems updating ubuntu kernel

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, virtualbox

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS on Virtual Box. I've some problems with the updating of my kernel and I don't know how to fix them! Reading others answer I tried with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and this is the report

```
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
Calcolo dell'aggiornamento... Fatto
I seguenti pacchetti saranno RIMOSSI:
linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic
0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 1 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
5 non completamente installati o rimossi.
Dopo quest'operazione, verranno liberati 156 MB di spazio su disco.
Continuare? [S/n] S
(Lettura del database... 232826 file e directory attualmente installati.)
Rimozione di linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic (4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2)...
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic/misc/vboxvideo.ko: Invalid argument
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.10.0-28-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd: Exec format error
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd exited with return code 1
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic (--remove):
il sottoprocesso installato script di post-removal ha restituito lo stato di errore 1
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: Did you try looking under https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/upgrade or https://superuser.com/search?q=ubuntu+upgrade?

Comment: Thank you so much, I manage to fix the problem following this

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014322/how-to-fix-configuration-issues-of-an-old-kernel-in-order-to-make-upgrade-possib

Comment: Please add your answer below, as an answer proper, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I managed to fix my kernel problem following the instructions in this site (I've to delete the references of the broken packages in var/lib/dpkg/status).

Here the site with the answer

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014322/how-to-fix-configuration-issues-of-an-old-kernel-in-order-to-make-upgrade-possib

Answer (score 0):

Even though the TO was able to solve the problem, I would like to suggest an easier way that worked for me and avoids the hassle to modify the dkpg manager files. Maybe it is worthwile and less dangerous to try this first.

So lately, I had a similar problem on a virtual machine. apt refused to update or install any packages with the these error messages:

```
    ...
    /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd:
    run-parts: failed to exec /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd: Exec format error
    run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd exited with return code 1
    ...
```

The file /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd turned out to be empty on my VM. This led me to the idea that VirtualBox GuestAdditions were broken. And indeed, after simply reinstalling the GuestAdditions, the apt problems were gone.